# Vim Pattern Searching in version 7.0.237

Tags: unix, vim

I am trying to learn how to use Redhat and I have come across a problem I can't solve after 2 days of Googling. I have been tasked with searching a large text document in VIM that has a line containing any of the character sequences: two, three, four, six or seven. My approach has been to treat these words as patterns and just search for that. Examples:

`\two.*three.*four.*six.*seven`

`\<two\>|....\<six\>|\<seven\>`

I am really struggling with this one. Any thoughts or advice would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can separate patterns using the `|` symbol. With default `magic` (see `:help magic`) you would need to escape the `|` i.e. `\|`.

So to search for two, three, four, six or seven enter:

```
/two\|three\|four\|six\|seven
```

Alternatively you could change the `magic` setting for the pattern using `\v` (*very magic*) then the `|` symbol has magic meaning within the pattern:

```
/\vtwo|three|four|six|seven
```

And if you only want to match between word boundaries, i.e. you do not want to match `sixteen` or `seventy`.

```
/\v<two>|<three>|<four>|<six>|<seven>
```

Or even:

```
/\v<(two|three|four|six|seven)>
```